# Prove that by removing a lineary dependent vector from a set A, we will not change the linear span of that set.

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there some easy to understand proof for the following?:

Proof that removing a lineary dependent vector from a set A will not change linear span of that set.

Comment: How can one single vector be linearly dependent unless it is the zero vector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A$ be a set of vectors, $v \in A$ be a linearly dependent vector in $A$ and consider the set $A \backslash \{v\}$. It is clear that $\text{span} (A \backslash \{v\}) \subseteq \text{span} (A)$, thus we only need to show that $\text{span}(A) \subseteq \text{span} (A \backslash \{v\})$:

Take a vector $w \in \text{span}(A)$, with $w = \lambda_{1}w_{1} + \cdots + \lambda_{n}w_{n}$ and $w_{j} \in A$. If $v \neq w_{j}$ for $1 \leqslant j \leqslant n$, then $w \in \text{span} (A \backslash \{v\})$. Now, if $v = w_{k}$ for some $k$, then we can write $v = w_{k}$ as a linear combination of vectors in $A \backslash \{v\}$, since $v$ is linearly dependent in $A$, so that we conclude that $w$ is a linear combination of vectors in $A \backslash \{v\}$, which means that $w \in \text{span} (A \backslash \{v\})$. Therefore, $\text{span}(A) \subseteq \text{span} (A \backslash \{v\})$ and we are done.

Comment: I understand, that if in the linear combination there is no lineary dependent vector $v$, than $w$ can be written as a linear combinations of vectors from a set $A \backslash \{v\}$. Also I understand that $v = w_{k}$ can be written as a linear combination of vectors in $A \backslash \{v\}$, since $w_{k}$ is lineary dependent. I don't understand the following though: If $w$ can be written as a linear combination $w = \lambda_{1}w_{1} + \cdots + \lambda_{k}w_{k} + \cdots + \lambda_{n}w_{n}$ , how does it implies, that $w$ can also be written as lin. comb. of vectors from $A \backslash \{v\}$?

Comment: I think the problem is in the definition of linear span. I thought that for linear combination $w = \lambda_{1}w_{1} + \cdots + \lambda_{n}w_{n}$, I can only use vectors in the set A, not the vectors I already "added" to the set by the previous linear combination, like the vector $w_{k}$.

Comment: If $v = w_{k}$, then write $v = \alpha_{1}v_{1} + \cdots + \alpha_{m}v_{m}$ with $v_{j} \in A \backslash \{v\}$. Then we obtain that $w = \lambda_{1}w_{1} + \cdots + \lambda_{k-1}w_{k-1} + \alpha_{1}v_{1} + \cdots + \alpha_{m}v_{m} +  \lambda_{k+1}w_{k+1} + \cdots +  \lambda_{n}w_{n}$, so $w$ is a linear combinations of vectors in $A \backslash \{v\}$.

Comment: How can one single vector be linearly dependent unless it is the zero vector?

Comment: @DonAntonio there is an abuse of language in this question/answer: when I said that $v \in A$ is a linearly dependent vector in $A$ I meant that $v$ makes the set $A$ linearly dependent, i.e. I meant that $v$ is a linear combination of vectors in $A$.

Comment: @VitorG. More than abuse of language that's plainly an incorrect language, and it caused me to confuse the title and I assumed "linearly dependent set". It should be said: if $\;A=\{v_1,...,v_n\}\;$ is any set (and it can be infinite as well) and $\;v_i\;$ is a vector linearly dependent in $\;B:=A\setminus\{v_i\}\;$ , then $\;Sp A= Sp B\;$ . Definitions must be clear and they shouldn't be misused to avoid confusion.

Comment: @DonAntonio Yes, I agree with you.